# How do you affect the translate node by the location of object?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I have this group input that generates a "lens flare":

[image: Node Tree]

I would like to know if it is possible to 'parent' the location of the flare to the sphere at the bottom of the image. I do not want to use any scripts [yet]. Any help would be appreciated. :)

[EDIT]

My menu options:

[image: Options]

Blender Render vs. Cycles [Help!]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you don't want to use scripts, I think you will have to use a driver to achieve what you want. Drivers can be a lot simpler than python scripts.

I'm thinking you want to alter the X value of the translate node. With your cursor over the X value, either press <kbd>D</kbd> or right click and select Add Driver, the value will then be highlighted in purple. The driver details are available in the graph editor, change F-Curve to Drivers in the graph editor header and select the value on the left, press <kbd>N</kbd> to show the properties panel on the right.

[image]

In this example the variable is named `getVal` and it will be equal to the X location of the object called Sphere. The scripted expression is set to `getVal * 10`, which means the X value of the translate node will be set to the Sphere's X location times 10.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if its what your looking for but the [Input > Object Info] node allows access to the vector location of the object in the current context...

from there basic maths should magic you up some results

best of luck =)

screenie =P

[image]

**Here are some links to some decent youtube channels that have helped me learn cycles**

https://www.youtube.com/user/AndrewPPrice

https://www.youtube.com/user/blendercookie

https://www.youtube.com/user/tutor4u

and of coarse blender.stackexchange is here for specific quesions

Comment: Didn't see the Object Info node...

Comment: what version of blender are you using?

Comment: 2.70 (Added this text to post the comment)

Comment: I am using the regular Blender Render, by the way

Comment: oh... my bad... i have no idea then... im sorry o.O

Comment: honestly i recommend moving to cycles in general... alot of good youtube vids focus of cycles, and global illumination is more expensive in the internal renderer

Comment: Actually, I do not see `Object Info` even when I am using Cycles Render.

Comment: Also… when I render with Cycles, I see a bunch of dots that make up a shape. Not sure what's going on here.

Comment: o.O thats strange... check the screenshot i added... its there for me... unless it was removed in the move from 2.69 > 2,7 (i haven't gotten the new one yet)

Comment: lighting works differently in cycles, all texturing is done with materials in the node editor, i think BI uses compositing, which i dont fully understand yet... also make sure your not in orthographic, sorry i cant be of more help. i never even tried to learn the internal renderer

Comment: and i think the dots have to do with the fact that cycles render incrementally... if your getting grainy images, you need to go to properties > render and increase the number of samples being used... also you may need to increase the power of your lights

Comment: Check the edit of the original post for screenshots. One image is split (photoshop).

Comment: looks like to need to texture your objects... this can be done in the [Properties > Materials] window or the [Node Editor] window... i would instruct youy on how to do so but that deserves is own full blown tutorial... i can however recommend a few youtube channels for learning the basics of cycles (wait for edit to post)

Comment: OK, I will check those links out. (I actually have watched some of those peoples' videos, but I'm sure they have something on the matter)

Comment: indeed... again im sorry i couldnt be of more help =(

Comment: I don't know if the Object Info node will help you, but I am using the 2.70 and the Object Info node does not appear to be available in Blender Render, but in Cycles, it is there, for me at least. Sometimes, though, the order the nodes are listed in the menus seems to invert, so maybe look again. Hope this helps.

Comment: You guys are mixing nodes, the question is in the compositor and object info is in materials. There isn't an equivalent to cycles object info in BI materials or compositor.

Comment: @sambler i didn't realize when i answered this that he was not using cycles, and like i said i haven't jumped into compositing yet, and i don't know anything about internal... it sucks but its the truth ='(